# How would I return this interface?

Tags: java, append

I am tasked with completing an append method which would return a list interface. A list interface is a class given which basically just has simple methods such as size(), append(), etc. In a new class, I had to write an append method using linked lists, and return a list interface. The problem is with my return because it says that ListInterface cannot be instantiated. If it helps at all, the class ListInterface only has methods which we must implement in our new class. Here's my append method:

```
public ListInterface<T> append(T elem)
{
    Node<T> curr= new Node<T>(elem,null);
    if(tail==null)
    {
        head=curr;
    }
    else
    {
        tail.setNext(curr);
    }
    tail=curr;
    size++;
    return new ListInterface<T>(head); //need help here
}
```

Comment: You need to create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: Where exactly is this method `append` declared? (And maybe showing the interface will also be of some help ...)

Comment: append is declared in the interface, but we define it in a new class where I implemented it.

Comment: So your new class _implements_ your list interface? In this case you already have the object that needs to be returned. It is the same object on which you called the `append` method. The last line then should simply be `return this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an object of a type that implements the interface ListInterface. It looks like you want to return "this" at the end of your method. I'm guessing your class implements ListInterface?

Comment: Yes that sounds like the correct solution to me. So you append "elem" to your list, and return your list.

Comment: Not necessarily. A method can return said interface as long as all the methods defined in it are implemented. (i.e. `return new Iterator<T>() { public boolean hasNext() {} public T next() {} public void remove() {}}`, though I don't know exactly what OP wants.)